# The timer in this c# program does not function

Tags: c#

When I type in a letter I get the current time which I have declared at the top and it does not work because after the certain amount of time declared the letter isn't locked in.

for example It will go from p to Q after 5 secs when I want it to go p(then save the letter in the textbox) then p again allowing me to make words

here is my code:

```
namespace MiniKeyboardAssignment
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //How long i've set my interval to go for, this means how long my timer will be on for before the current letter is saved//
        int timerinterval = 2000;


        bool button_but1 = true;
        int Button1_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but2 = true;
        int Button2_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but3 = true;
        int Button3_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but4 = true;
        int Button4_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but5 = true;
        int Button5_Clicked = -1;
        bool button_but6 = true;
        int Button6_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but7 = true;
        int Button7_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but8 = true;
        int Button8_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but9 = true;
        int Button9_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but10 = true;
        int Button10_clicked = -1;
        bool button_but12 = true;
        int Button12_clicked = -1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Mode_TextBox.Text = "Multipress";
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
            counter++;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(counter);
            timer1.Enabled = true; 
     }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sequence1 = "1";
            if (button_but1 == true)
            {
                Button1_clicked++;
                textbox.Text = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items[Button1_clicked]);
                listBox11.Items.Add(sequence1);
                counter++;
                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(counter);
                button_but1 = false;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Button1_clicked++;
            }
            characterstring[Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text)] = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items[Button1_clicked]);
            textbox.Text = characterstring[0] + characterstring[1] + characterstring [2] + characterstring [3] + characterstring [4] + characterstring [5] + characterstring [6] + characterstring [7] + characterstring [8] + characterstring [9] + characterstring [10] + characterstring [11] + characterstring [12] + characterstring [13] + characterstring [14] + characterstring [15] + characterstring [16] + characterstring [17] + characterstring [18] + characterstring [19] + characterstring [20];
        }
```

Comment: No idea what you are talking about...

Comment: You have way too much here. Please try to narrow down your problem and simplify your question. You are throwing way to much code for people to just go in cold and figure it out. You are unlikely to get any helpful answers unless you narrow the scope of your question.

Comment: alright i've edited to the bit relevant

Comment: Sorry you are getting downvoted and close votes. Yes everyone he's clearly a bit new at this, but he has a legitimate problem, and is asking it as well as he can. His question is on topic for SO to boot. Give the guy a chance. Sometimes SO is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have properly initialized your textBox and timer:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.Text = "1";
        this.timer1.Interval = timerInterval;
        this.timer1.Start();
    }
```

Also, you don't need to set timer1.Enabled in your timer1_Tick method. Setting Enabled to true is the same as calling Start (which, in my example, is done in the constructor.) Alternatively, you can continue to only enable the timer when button1 is clicked.